# Обработка функций кнопками

Tags: javascript, html

Почему при нажатии любой из кнопок ничего не происходит, в консоли тоже никакого "фидбека". Проверял в нескольких браузерах и вебшторме, ничего не происходит, тут воспроизводится.

```html
            <button type="button" onclick="loadContent('text')">Загрузить текст</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="loadContent('image')">Загрузить изображение</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="loadContent('file')">Загрузить файл</button>

            <div id="content"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<script>
    var textContent = 'условие';
    var imagePath = "img/Screenshot 2023-10-28 234434.png";
    var filePath = "src/html_content.txt";

    function loadContent(type) {
        var contentDiv = document.getElementById('content');
        contentDiv.innerHTML = '';

        switch(type) {
            case 'text':
                contentDiv.innerHTML = textContent;
                break;
            case 'image':
                const img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = imagePath;
                contentDiv.appendChild(img);
                break;
            case 'file':
                const obj = document.createElement('object');
                obj.data = filePath;
                obj.width = "100%";
                obj.height = "100%";
                contentDiv.appendChild(obj);
                break;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Я ваши кнопки потыкал - работает визуально...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вы или передавайте event в html: `onclick="loadText(event)"`, либо не вызывайте `preventDefault()` в функции (а для button он и не нужен)

```html
    <tr>
        <td style="width:50%;
                   height:80%;">
            <button onclick="loadText()">Загрузить текст</button>
            <button onclick="loadImage()">Загрузить изображение</button>
            <button onclick="loadFile()">Загрузить файл</button>

            <div id="content"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    var textContent = 'условие';
    var imagePath = "img/Screenshot 2023-10-28 234434.png";
    var filePath = "src/html_content.txt";


function loadText() {
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = textContent;
}

function loadImage() {
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = imagePath;
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(img);
}

function loadFile() {
    const obj = document.createElement('object');
    obj.data = filePath;
    obj.width = "100%";
    obj.height = "100%";
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(obj);
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: да это мой косяк что я обновил в вопросе только скрипт, а о кнопках забыл. Но во всяком случае в  конструкторе на сайте оно работает, в  других же браузерах — нет. Как перед этим упоминал человек(потом он удалил сообщение с дискуссией), что preventDefault()  нужен для того что бы при нажатии кнопки страница не обновлялась. Но и в таком случае, у меня нажатия на кнопки не дают никакого результата.

Comment: @AfteRDay подобное поведение мб у ссылок и при сабмите формы. там для того чтобы избежать перезагрузки и юзается preventDefault

Comment: а есть идеи с чем может связанно то что оно тут на сайте работает, а в браузере нет?

Comment: @AfteRDay возможно какое то кэширование... попробуйте в консоли браузера обратитесь к функции из файла, есть ли она там

Comment: переделал немного функцию, обращаюсь к ней и выдаёт такой результат:
window.loadContent('image') ->
undefined;
window.loadContent("text")->
undefined

Comment: это значит что функции есть. тогда у меня нет мыслей почему не работает. я просто взял и перенес ваш код js в консоль. далее вызвал первую функцию и она сработала.

Comment: в общем решил я переписать код и у меня вышло, только получилась загвоздка, я парсю файл, в которой код аштмл-страницы и вставляю в "iframe", но выходит так, что у меня в "фрейме" в результате рендерится страница, а не текст кода. Как можно сделать что бы   у меня в результате был текст кода.
"""
    function displayFileContent(){
        fetch(filePath)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                var iframe = document.getElementById('contentContainer');
                iframe.srcdoc = data;
            });
    }

"""

Comment: задайте этот вопрос отдельно, добавив нормально код. если мой ответ оказался полезным, оцените его.